# api-ms-win-crt-runtime-|1-1-0.dll error while installing Unity

Tags: dll, system-error

I tried to install Unity editor separately from https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive  without using Unity hub or the installer.After the installation when  I opened it , it shows the error api-ms-win-crt-runtime-|1-1-0.dll is missing.
I used a method which I saw in this youtube video : https://youtu.be/lLzzbnfVXUU and did the directX method .It still did not work. 
Then after reading a blog , I downloaded the missing dll file and pasted it in the system32 folder.After that when I tried to open it showed that another .dll file was missing .This time it was a different file.I downloaded and pasted it in the system32 folder.Then again another .dll file is missing and the process continued.

My questions are :

- Is there any other way ?
- Should I keep downloading these .dll files ?

Comment: why not just use unity hub?

Comment: @vasmos I got an error that I didn't have enough space and also I prefer doing like the method I wrote in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mind I got it.Just continue installing the .dll files.The site I downloaded is https://www.dll-files.com/  .